# Python Cron Job in Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, cron

I have three files which is

- crontab : lists of cron job to be execute
- entrypoint.sh

  ```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
  ```

  service cron start
  python

and docker file basically to install the pip and to run crontab on certain folder.

My question is :
Why in my docker container, the cron just start once and Exited. have no ways to find the logs of it as it shows : Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.

i wish to know whats the proper way of setting up and how to keep it running.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways on how you can run a cronjob inside a docker container. Here is an example for a cron-setup on **debian** using **cronjob files**.

## Create a crontab file

```
  * * * * * root echo "Test my-cron" > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

*my-cron* - This file contains the **interval**, **user** and the **command** that should be scheduled. In this example we want to print the text *Test my-cron* every minute.

## Create a docker entrypoint

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cron                   # start cron service

tail -f /dev/null      # keep container running
```

*entrypoint.sh* - This is the entrypoint which gets executed when the container gets started.

## Create a Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y cron

# Cron file
ADD ./my-cron /etc/cron.d/my-cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/my-cron

# Entrypoint
ADD ./entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh

CMD [ "entrypoint.sh" ]
```

## Run

### Build the image

```
docker build . --tag my-cron
```

### Start a container

```
docker run -d my-cron:latest
```

### Check the console output

```
docker logs <YOUR_CONTAINER_ID> --follow
```